# How to Add multiple objects in local Storage instead of overwriting it

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I am trying to store this information in Local storage but i don't want it to overwrite the data instead i want it append it in the object i created in local storage
Js code

```
function addToCartClicked(event)
{
    var button = event.target
    var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
    var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-title')[0].innerText
    var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-price')[0].innerText
    var imgSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('shop-item-image')[0].src
    console.log(title)

    addItemToCart(title,price,imgSrc)

}

function addItemToCart(title,price,imgSrc)
{
    var product = {
        title   : title,
        price   : price,
        imgSrc  :  imgSrc
      };
      console.log(product)
      localStorage.setItem("productsInCart" ,JSON.stringify(product))
}
```

python Code

```
<section class="container content-section">
            <h2 class="section-header">On Sale</h2>
            <div class="shop-items">
                {% for data in product_data %}
                    <div class="shop-item" >
                        <span class="shop-item-title" id="title-item">{{ data.title }}</span>
                        <input type="image" class="shop-item-image" id="image-item" src={{ data["img_file"] }} onclick="takethatpage();">
                        <div class="shop-item-details">
                            <span class="shop-item-price" id="price-item">{{ data["price"]}}</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %} 
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can very well use an array of objects to store

read more here https://www.kirupa.com/html5/storing_and_retrieving_an_array_from_local_storage.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use array to store multiple object on local storage.
So you can modify your code like :

```
function addItemToCart(title,price,imgSrc)
{
    var products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productsInCart")||"[]"); // get current objects
    var product = {
      title   : title,
      price   : price,
      imgSrc  :  imgSrc
    };

    products.push(product); //push new one

    console.log(product)
    localStorage.setItem("productsInCart" ,JSON.stringify(products))
}
```

---

[Test app on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V4RmNwM3GTcdlKff)

Comment: its Not appending it and giving an error in console products .push is not a function

Comment: but if add square brackets like this it doesn't gives an error on push thing but its overwriting data in local storage var product = [{
      title   : title,
      price   : price,
      imgSrc  :  imgSrc
    }];

Comment: I tested it on plunker and its working very well. Could you check your code with it?